# How to remove extra blank lines

Tags: python

I would like to remove any *extra* empty lines in this string and store it in a different string, single empty lines must remain.

```
mystring1 = """This is line 1


            This is line 2
            This is line 3



            This is line 4

            This is line 5"""
```

**Desired Output :**

```
mystring2 = """This is line 1

            This is line 2
            This is line 3

            This is line 4

            This is line 5"""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `re` to catch **two or more** blank lines:

```
print(re.sub("\n\n+", "\n\n", mystring1))
This is line 1

This is line 2
This is line 3

This is line 4

This is line 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use re and replace 2 or more lines with \n\n:

```
mystring1 = """This is line 1


This is line2
This is line3



This is line4

This is line5
"""

import re
mystring2 = re.sub(r'\n{2,}', '\n\n', mystring1)

mystring2
This is line 1

This is line2
This is line3

This is line4

This is line5
```

Comment: While that is a good solution, in this problem I may have even more than two blank lines.

Comment: @Labrinth I have made few changes and let me know if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the desired output, use `re.sub("\n{2,}", "\n\n", mystring1)`:

```
>>> mystring1 = """This is line 1


            This is line 2
            This is line 3



            This is line 4

            This is line 5"""
>>> mystring2 = re.sub("\n{2,}", "\n\n", mystring1)
>>> print(mystring2)
This is line 1

            This is line 2
            This is line 3

            This is line 4

            This is line 5
```

If you want to remove all extra newlines except for one, you can use `` like so:

```
>>> mystring2 = re.sub("\n+", "\n", mystring1)
>>> print(mystring2)
This is line 1
            This is line 2
            This is line 3
            This is line 4
            This is line 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
import os
mystring1 = """This is line 1


            This is line 2
            This is line 3



            This is line 4

            This is line 5"""

mystring1 = os.linesep.join([s for s in mystring1.splitlines() if s])

print(mystring1)
```

Output:

```
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
This is line 4
This is line 5
```